# For which numbers of nodes can a connected graph be arranged in such a way that each edge has 2 intersections?

Tags: graph-theory

Assume you have a set of $n$ points which are part of a connected graph. Every node should have degree $2$, i.e.
every point is connected to two other points and therefore the graph also has $n$ edges (edges are only allowed to be straight line segments).

I'd like to know for which $n$ you can arange the points in such a way that every edge has an even number of intersections with other edges (nodes are defined never to be exactly on an edge; 0 intersections don't count).

And a more special case would be for which $n$ each edge can have exactly 2 (or any other natural number of) intersections.

For $n=3$ and $n=4$ it is obviously not possible, as for $3$ there aren't any intersections at all, and for $4$ there are at least two edges without any intersection.

For $n=5$ it is rather easy to find a case where each edge has $2$ intersections by simply connecting them in the shape of a star.

I don't think it's possible for $n=6$ but I'm struggling to find a method to proof it.

For $n=7$ you can also make a star-shape to get $4$ intersections on each edge (I haven't found an example for $2$), and for $n=8$ I *have* once again found an example with $2$ intersections each.
[image: Non-trivial example for n=8]

I have not tried anything for $n>8$ yet nor have I been able to work out any steps for a potential proof.

Any help to find a proof would be greatly appreciated! (You don't have to write a finished proof as an answer, I'd also be happy if you can suggest some techniques I could use)

Comment: Look up star polygons, specifically the $\{n, 2 \}$ type (naming might be different).

Comment: Oh, that makes so much sense, how did I not see those myself. Thanks!

Comment: @299792458 Interesting question! please clarify that an edge in the question means a line segment on a fixed Euclidean plane. If an edge can be a curve, it is easy to construct various examples even for $n=3$.

Comment: @299792458 Can you include an image for the case of $n=8$ where each edge has 2
 intersections?  That should be a nontrivial example.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I included the non-trivial example I found. Do you know for which other n there are non-trivial solutions?

Answer (score 1):

If we have such a drawing for an $a$-point cycle and a $b$-point cycle, then we can combine them to get a drawing for an $(a+b)$-point cycle. For example, here is a drawing where we join the $7$-point construction to the $9$-point construction:

[image]

In general, to do this, pick a point on each cycle that's not "in the middle": it can be pulled out to be an extreme in one direction. Split each cycle apart at that point into two points, so that it becomes a path. Then glue those paths at their ends. (This works very generally, whenever we have some restriction on the number of intersections along each edge, since we do not gain or lose any such intersections.)

When we want exactly two intersections per edge, we have a construction for an $n$-point cycle where $n = 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, \dots$ by going around a circle two steps at a time, as seen in each color above. By combining the $5$-point cycle with the $k$-point cycle for $k=5, 7, 9, \dots$, we get an $n$-point cycle for $n=10, 12, 14, 16, \dots$. We also have a construction (given in the question) for an $8$-point cycle.

This gives us all values of $n$ except $n \le 4$ and $n=6$, and the question shows how to rule out $n \le 4$, leaving only the case of $n=6$ open.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just to let you know, I'm not yet marking this as answered as the case for $n=6$ is still open. I'm also wondering whether there are non-trivial constructions for all odd $n$...

Comment: What do you consider "non-trivial"; just the construction that's not the circular one? Well, for all odd $n \ge 13$, we can split $n$ as $(n-8)+8$ and get a different construction that way. For $n=5$, we are limited to only one possible construction, because each edge must cross exactly the two edges it doesn't share an endpoint with. For $n=7, 9, 11$ it's possible that we can do something unusual. (Finally, I don't have a proof yet, but strongly expect that $n=6$ is impossible.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean with non-trivial: a way of arranging the points such that they don't form a star-polygon. I know that you can get all $n \ge 13$ by combining smaller star-polygons the way you described. But what are the "non-trivial" ones for $n = 7, 9, 11$? By combining two star-polygons you can't get less than 10 endpoints and if $n=6$ is not possible, $n=11$ can also not be constructed in such a way

Comment: I don't have any nontrivial examples for $n=7,9,11$, I just can't rule them out.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood you. Do you have any idea on how you could find a proof that it's impossible with $n=6,7,9,11$?